# Is there a way of copying a file from on branch to another but with different name?

Tags: git, github

“I’m having two branches i.e master and minified, and I want to be able to copy a file from master to minified but get it with a different name.

I have tried  git checkout

```
git checkout master index.html
```

I want index.html to be copied to minified as maybe

`index_from_master.html`

Comment: What is your goal - seems that you want to use the git in inappropriate way. What do you want to achieve? In general you should keep the code base synchronized.

Comment: Why not just copy the file on master. Then on master you have the copy which is untracked. Then just checkout to the other branch an add it there.

Comment: `git show master:index.html > index_from_master.html`

Comment: Thank you FreshD and Arkdiusz they both methods you gave me work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
git checkout minified
git show master:index.html > index_from_master.html # get content and write to new file
```

Also, if `index.html` does not exist on branch `minified`:

```
git checkout minified
git checkout master -- index.html # checkout file
git mv index.html index_from_master.html # rename file
```

If `index.html` already exists and you don't want to replace it with the version in `master`, you could first temporarily rename `index.html` in `minified` and do the above. Or without the temporarily renaming:

```
git checkout minified
git checkout master -- index.html # replacing the index.html from minified if any
git mv index.html index_from_master.html
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/minified -- index.html # get file back from working area
```